# Scroll with easing

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel, easing

I have spent a lot of time to finding a jquery code that ensures that I can scroll with an easing effect.

I know that you can manipulate it with jQuery Mousewheel but i can't archieve the easing effect like: http://www.loisjeans.com/web2012/es

I appreciate all the help I can get to put me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm guessing they have a lot of things that are in a `fixed` position (hence unaffected by scroll), and then listening to scroll and applying an animation with easing.

Comment: Off-topic, but I just have to say. Holy mother of god, that is some awesome designing.

Answer (score 2):

If by easing you mean inertia try iScroll.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply - iScroll is a great example except the mousewheel funtion is not included, that's the part i'm seeking for

Comment: The mousewheel support is there but yes it seems it doesnt support inertia effect but I bet its possible to edit or write your own function that will call iScroll and preserve inertia.

Answer (score 1):

idbranding

Please spend some time on making your scroll with http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller, cause it does work

use 100% height and width on your scroll container
then you can add css on your body that have 100% height and width, and by applying overflow:hidden you remove the normal scrollbar and can just style your new scroll bar in place.

It does work :D

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Comment: Thanks rgin, i have tried that solutions.. can't get it to work on my body.. i have to place it in some container wich screws my parallax up.. :( - it also doesn't work on iphone and tablet